# How run 'sbt update' in eclipse IDE?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-ide

I wrote project dependency set in `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
   Seq(
           "net.liftweb" %% "lift-webkit" % liftVersion % "compile",
           "net.liftweb" %% "lift-mapper" % liftVersion % "compile",

   )
 }
```

next, 
in terminal console,
I input `sbt update` & `sbt eclipse`

but, I want to use only Eclipse IDE

How can I do that?

(eclipse plugin used  : `Scala-ide for eclipse v3.0.0`)

Comment: Currently AFAIK, you cannot do it from eclipse directly. Are you doing `refresh` in eclipse after doing `sbt eclipse`?

Comment: As a advise you may look at Intellij IDEA with it's Scala plugin and SBT plugin, it can do exectly what you want and much more =)

Comment: to Jatin : right! but I want no using 'console'  & only 'IDE'

Comment: to Alexlv : oh~ Really? thx. when develop python project, I use pycharm (like Intellij) I will try ~! thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the Eclipse plugin won't do that. We'll get to that eventually, but for the moment you need to run `sbt eclipse` (and refresh the project, if you haven't enabled auto-refresh). Hopefully you don't need to do that too often. ;-)